# Move Minecraft to SSD

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

***Note:*** [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179373/how-to-transfer-minecraft-root-folder-to-an-ssd-drive) is now outdated, due to the new Minecraft Launcher

I have Windows 10 installed on an HDD, and I bought a small 60GB SSD to store games on, since I heard SSD loaded games faster. I want to move all of my Minecraft files onto the SSD, and have the launcher realize that it's there.

Yes, the drive is formatted as NTFS, and Windows can see the drive. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple - it's pretty much a copy and paste job.

1. Find the location of where your current launcher is located.  Mine is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\`
2. Copy this `Minecraft` folder, and paste it into your new SSD wherever you'd like
3. Find where the actual game files are (the `.minecraft` file).  Mine are located at `C:\Users\Gamem\AppData\Roaming`.  You may need to enable ["Hidden Items" within File Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/) so that you can see the `AppData` file.  Note that the `Gamem` part of the path will be whatever your user name is
4. Copy the `.minecraft` folder and paste it into your SSD wherever you'd like.
5. Launch the launcher from your SSD, and go to "Launch Options."
6. Click on the release version, and press the switch to the left of the "Game Directory" to enable the text box
7. Paste in the file path of where your `.minecraft` file is on your SSD
8. Save, and the game should load from here now when you launch it

[image: Launcher]

Note that you shouldn't have to move the launcher to your SSD, just the game files. If you don't want to the move the launcher, skip to step 3.  Also remember that if you are copying and pasting (and not cutting and pasting), you will have duplicate files in different locations.  This shouldn't matter, but it will take up more space on your disks.  So, either delete them after you move them, or just leave them.

Comment: So OP was wrong, and the steps pretty much haven't changed at all other than it's a new launcher. :/

Comment: @MageXy I guess technically.  The new launcher appears to be more user friendly.  For those new to Minecraft entirely, and never seen the old launcher, it may still be useful.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change where the .minecraft file is stored in general. Only this version is stored to the SSD