# How to install Minecraft in a different folder/on a different drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have to move it onto the D: Drive because it has 2 TB while the default C: Drive only remains 32 GB (117 max storage which mysteriously lost alot of storage). The Minecraft launcher is installed in D:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher (Program Files (x86) is made by me and just to make an illusion to the C: Drive).

Comment: The same way that you move it to any folder.

Comment: its not that simple. have you even played minecraft? it will make a new installation as if ive installed miencraft for the first time

Comment: You mean your worlds or the game itself?

Comment: the game itself .minecraft
i asked questions in reddit and its more descriptive.

Comment: Ah, ok, you mean the entire installation. There are lots of questions here all the time about moving the worlds etc., so I assumed you meant that. I changed the title now to be more clear, can you please do the same with the question text? I don't really know what you mean with "illusion", do you mean a hardlink? Also, I have a lot of versions and other things in my original .minecraft folder (but not the worlds and stuff) and it only takes up 1GB. Is that already too much for you? Maybe cleaning up some old versions that you don't need anymore could help.

Comment: My dad told me I have to install everything on D: drive because c: drive lacks much storage. Illusion as in a program files folder in the d drive like from c drive

Comment: Also my original .Minecraft was around 9 gb when I used tlauncher to relocate Minecraft before officially buying a premium account

Comment: If you bought anything called "premium", you've been scammed, immediately refund the payment! There is only one kind of Minecraft account (for JE) and you can buy it only from minecraft.net!

Comment: no i bought my minecraft account from minecraft.net. i originally got minecraft cracked from tlauncher which i have limited access to servers. i can relocate it using tlauncher. DANG WHY DOES THIS HAVE TO BE SO COMPLICATED

Comment: I'm never using stack exchange again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you move or transfer a Minecraft root folder to another drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179373/how-can-you-move-or-transfer-a-minecraft-root-folder-to-another-drive)

Comment: bruh I posted this nearly 4 years ago lmao