# How can I move my Minecraft installation to another drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

I installed Minecraft before getting my 1TB SSD, and now I want to move it. My C drive is very low on space and I'm trying to keep it free of games. Is there any way I can completely move Minecraft to another drive with all my data intact?

I'm on windows 10 right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you move or transfer a Minecraft root folder to another drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179373/how-can-you-move-or-transfer-a-minecraft-root-folder-to-another-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone in the future here's how I did it! It was super easy actually. I just moved the folder to the other drive. I then used a directory junction to put a kind of shortcut in the original location. This kind of shortcut basically just appears as if the install is there, without it needing to be there, it basically redirects programs. I can't explain how to do it exactly, but google how to make symlinks (and use [this](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) tool to make it much easier)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best and safest approach - with some side effects, although IMO beneficial ones - would be to use [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/). It's an alternative launcher that helps managing multiple instances of the game - it's especially valuable when you play modded, as you can have many conflicting modpacks, various versions in non-conflicting instances, no risk of corrupting your worlds by opening them with wrong version, plus it makes installing mods a breeze - but even if you play pure vanilla, it's still helpful, allowing you to keep worlds separate between different versions. The only actual downside is a bit of extra hassle when upgrading a world to newest version (create a new instance, manually copy the save from older to newer), but it's very helpful in a lot of other respects, and can be installed anywhere. After installing and creating the instance of game matching the version you play, from the instance menu choose 'open instance folder', pick .minecraft, saves, and move/copy your world from %appdata%/.minecraft/saves using Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to move the vanilla Minecraft installation.

Comment: @Emerald_Guy123 MultiMC is an alternate launcher but it normally runs regular vanilla Minecraft - it only makes modding it much easier but by no means mandatory.

Comment: Yeah, just what I meant was that I want to move my vanilla installation, like the .minecraft folder. I already have a total of 3 clients (Badlion, vanilla, Twitch).

Comment: @Emerald_Guy123 Maybe a method exists, I don't know it. A sure-fire 'pure vanilla' method is to start a dedicated (vanilla) server on your computer and then connect to it using the 'multiplayer' option - that way all the heavyweight stuff (the world save) is kept with the server wherever you install it, and the client can be kept slim. Alternatively read up on `junctions` in Windows. Using them you can 'transparently' link up a directory from another drive to a directory on C:

Comment: Okay. I think I'm just gonna try reinstalling Minecraft entirely.

Comment: @Emerald_Guy123: Note the Minecraft installation itself is pretty small (280MB). The largest piece is your world, which is in `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves/[world name]`, - your user's personal directory, and this is the thing that can grow into many gigabytes if you're an avid explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to go into your launcher, edit your profile and change the path where your world / profile sould be stored.
But the launcher config will sill stay on your userdir in `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` (in your case `C:\Users\Emerald_Guy123\AppData\Roaming`.

A way to move your complete minecraft workdir is to start your minecraft with the command argument `--workDir`.
The best way to have an easy (even portable) minecraft would is

1. create a textfile `start minecraft.bat` in your desired directory
2. insert this code

```
@echo off
Minecraft.exe --workDir .\_profile\YOUR_NAME
```

3. create the folder `_profile\YOUR_NAME`
4. (optional) when you already have existing profiledata or worlds, move them in the new folder

And to start minecraft click on the `start minecraft.bat` instead of the exe file.
Minecraft will store all your profiledata and your worlds in the directory `\_profile\YOUR_NAME` in the drive/folder where you stored the `.bat`-file.