# How do I change my .minecraft folder location to another drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to move my .minecraft folder to another drive. I have already copied it to the desired location, but I cannot find a way to change the folder location.
I tried running this script in the same folder as the minecraft launcher exe, but I cannot find it. It was not in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\ or  C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\ folders (Neither of which exist).
How can I do this?
New launcher btw.

Comment: What script? Which launcher?

Comment: which launcher? the minecraft one.

Comment: and this one - @echo off
start MinecraftLauncher.exe --workDir FOLDER

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move my Minecraft installation to another drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376136/how-can-i-move-my-minecraft-installation-to-another-drive)

Comment: i saw it but i didnt understand what he was talking about or how to do what he did so i asked my own question