# How can I increase FPS in games (Minecraft, various Steam games) on my low-mid end computer? Specs below

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam, framerate, nvidia-geforce-experience

```
Specs:
    Intel Core i7-6500U @ 2.50GHz x 4
    HP ENVY Notebook
    16384MB RAM
    Display: Intel HD Graphics 520
    Render: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 940M
    Windows 10 Pro version 1909
```

*(I typed that out from dxdiag without using the save all info button)*

It seems that my computer has sufficient hardware, but I need to clean up files that slow down my computer and I don't know which ones. I have already run Disk Cleanup and Optimize Drives.

Let me know if you need any more specs.
I normally get 20-30 fps.

This question has been flagged as a possible duplicate of [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft), so here's why not:

> OptiFine (Minecraft Forum Link) reworks a number of rendering details to improve Minecraft performance (+20fps). Many people go crazy about it on the forum, others say that it just doesn't work so YMMV.

I have already installed OptiFine and tried other mods such as Sodium.

> Within the options menu (Esc -> Options), set Graphics to Fast and set Render Distance to Tiny.

I have done this and saw a small performance increase. (~10 fps)

> Close any programs you can spare to lose (ie internet browser, messenger, music).
> If you're really desperate, you can open your task manager (Ctrl + Alt + Delete -> Start Task Manager) and select the "Processes" tab. Order by "Memory" and have a look at what's taking up so much processing power on your computer (Minecraft will be listed as javaw.exe). Use the End Process button to stop a selected process.

I use Razer Cortex for this and it does a pretty good job.

> Change Minecraft's processing priority.

This actually doesn't affect my FPS in any way.

> If all else fails, you might have to upgrade your computer. You can get plenty of cheap, new choices at Amazon.com.

Yes, thinking of trying this.

All other answers to the question were out of date. I would like to get some new answers to this issue on Arqade!

Could you also extend help to software like Unity or Blender?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I do not know about other games, but in minecraft, which version of the game do you specifically want to increase the fps of?

If you are playing bedwars/skywars/some other pvp based multiplayer game, I suggest use a fps boost client like [badlion](https://www.badlion.net/), [salwyrr](https://www.salwyrr.com/) or [lunar](https://www.lunarclient.com/).

If you want to play survival in latest versions, use optifine. As you said you already do, to significantly increase fps, go in video settings > performance and turn smart animations to on. As you said you already have turned the game performance to fast, in the performance settings, hover over each setting and it will show it's description. Read it and set it to the fastest/fps increasing mode. Try turning all particles to off/low.

Seeing your computer graphics, and comparing with mine, your pc is a beast. But still my pc doesn't run minecraft with low fps. Maybe this is the case as I have not stored much data on my C: drive but stored it on F: drive and my minecraft is stored on the C: drive. Maybe due to that my system can access the minecraft files easily. I maybe totally wrong, but It *may* be the case. Try doing this and see if it helps. [If anyone needs help in shifting minecraft from C: to another location, this might help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179373/how-can-you-move-or-transfer-a-minecraft-root-folder-to-another-drive).

Also I personally use salwyrr for bedwars and I play on 1.8.8 and I get 60 to 180 cps fluctuating. Try this if an multiplayer pvp based game is what you want.

```
Specs of my pc are : 
Processor       : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.20 GHz
Ram             : 8.00 GB
System type     : 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Graphics Card   : AMD Radeon (TM) R9 M375
```

I hope this helped :D .

Comment: I do already use Salwyrr. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question. I'll try the alternate drive idea! I have 1.19 TB available of 1.8 TB so I don't know if it'll help. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, how would I move Minecraft to my other volume?

Comment: _So, I do not know about other games, but in minecraft, which version of the game do you specifically want to increase the fps of?_ 1.8, 1.16 and 1.17.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to ask, like what do you mean by other volume?
and I use 1.16 with optifine and earlier I used to et 10 to 20 fps but after turning on smart animations, it significantly increased to 40, do try smart animations. I haven't tried 1.17 yet, so I don't know. Also, salwyrr comes with optifine installed, try turning smart animations on in it,  And I will edit my answer to the settings I use in salwyrr and 1.16 by 6pm IST as I have to study till then.

Comment: If you meant to move mc to another disk, I edited my answer, in para 4 last line, I added a link that might help you.

Comment: Thanks! I meant another disk. I will see if smart transitions work.

Comment: Smart transitions don't change fps much. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Your welcome, Glad to help, did changing drive affect performance?

Comment: Yes it did! Not much though it is more stable now. 30-40 fps with smart anims in a superflat.